# Moving primary domain controller to a different Azure virtual network

Tags: azure, domaincontroller, virtual-network

I have created an Azure virtual network with a specific address space - 10.0.0.0/8. I created a subnet beneath it, 10.10.0.0/16, and added several machines to this subnet, including a PDC and a BDC, which are also acting as DNS servers.

Unfortunately, that is not exactly what I meant to do, I meant to create the address space as 10.10.0.0/16, with the intent of connecting it to some other virtual networks using S2S VPN gateways. The other virtual networks are set up using address spaces configured as: 10.x.0.0/16

To rectify the situation, based on what I could find here and on MSDN, I created a new virtual network in the same region with the correct address space (10.10.0.0/16), then deleted the VMs in the old virtual network (but left the VHDs) and recreated the VMs in the new virtual network using the old VHDs.

This seems to be working as expected. Now I am down to the domain controllers and one other machine. Will there be any issues with following the same process to move a domain controller? I realize the system GUID will be different, but was not sure if this impacts anything relative to AD and the DNS servers.

TIA for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no impacts from the AD perspectives. From a DNS perspective, Azure assigned IP addresses to the machines in the order that they were restarted, so to avoid confusing DNS, I restarted the VMs in order of increasing IP address.

Needed to make sure SQL Server data volumes were attached before starting the machine, otherwise  the database would show as being in a pending recovery state.

Also, apps that depend on MAC address (such as some license servers) did require new license files, as the MAC address changed.